# Why doesn't this code for an 8x8 LED matrix work properly?

Tags: arduino-uno, led-matrix

There's an Arduino Uno (Keyestudio KS0078) and a 788BS 8x8 LED matrix.
I built the circuit as on the image and ran this program:

```cpp
#define MY_PERIOD 200

int displayColumn = 0;
uint32_t tmr1;

unsigned char Text[] = { 0x00, 0x1c, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1c };

void Draw_point(unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
  clear();
  digitalWrite(x + 2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, LOW);
  delay(1);
}

void show_num(void) {
  unsigned char i, j, data;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    data = Text[i];
    data <<= displayColumn;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (data & 0x01) {
        Draw_point(j, i);
      }
      data >>= 1;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 2; i < 18; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
  clear();
}

void loop() {
  show_num();
  if (millis() - tmr1 >= MY_PERIOD) {
    tmr1 = millis();
    displayColumn++;
    if (displayColumn > 7) {
      displayColumn = 0;
    }
  }
}

void clear() {
  for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  for (int i = 10; i < 18; i++)
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
}
```

[image: circuit]

I got the code from the [Keyestudio examples wiki](https://wiki.keyestudio.com/KS0077%2878,79%EF%BC%89Super_Learning_Kit_for_Arduino#Project_19:_8*8_LED_Matrix) and added a part with `displayColumn` and shifting to the left every 0.2 sec. But instead of fading out fully on the 7th step, one LED (x=0, y=6) stays on. Even if I stop executing `show_num` when `displayColumn > 7` it stays on as long as there is power. Why?

UPD: I removed dynamic shifting in `loop` and set `displayColumn` in 5, 6 and 7 - the display showed correct result and was empty when `displayColumn` was equal to 7. Obviously the bug hides between "transitions".

UPD2: If I try the programm with other symbol, the bug on the step 7 always repeats with other LED which was the last lighted one on the step 6.

UPD3: Debug data by request of @thebusybee (repeated blocks removed)

```
x,y:2,1 x,y:3,1 x,y:4,1
x,y:1,2 x,y:5,2
x,y:1,3 x,y:5,3
x,y:1,4 x,y:5,4
x,y:1,5 x,y:5,5
x,y:1,6 x,y:5,6
x,y:2,7 x,y:3,7 x,y:4,7
displayColumn: 1
x,y:3,1 x,y:4,1 x,y:5,1
x,y:2,2 x,y:6,2
x,y:2,3 x,y:6,3
x,y:2,4 x,y:6,4
x,y:2,5 x,y:6,5
x,y:2,6 x,y:6,6
x,y:3,7 x,y:4,7 x,y:5,7
displayColumn: 2
x,y:4,1 x,y:5,1 x,y:6,1
x,y:3,2 x,y:7,2
x,y:3,3 x,y:7,3
x,y:3,4 x,y:7,4
x,y:3,5 x,y:7,5
x,y:3,6 x,y:7,6
x,y:4,7 x,y:5,7 x,y:6,7
displayColumn: 3
x,y:5,1 x,y:6,1 x,y:7,1
x,y:4,2
x,y:4,3
x,y:4,4
x,y:4,5
x,y:4,6
x,y:5,7 x,y:6,7 x,y:7,7
displayColumn: 4
x,y:6,1 x,y:7,1
x,y:5,2
x,y:5,3
x,y:5,4
x,y:5,5
x,y:5,6
x,y:6,7 x,y:7,7
displayColumn: 5
x,y:7,1
x,y:6,2
x,y:6,3
x,y:6,4
x,y:6,5
x,y:6,6
x,y:7,7
displayColumn: 6


x,y:7,2
x,y:7,3
x,y:7,4
x,y:7,5
x,y:7,6

displayColumn: 7

//many many empty strings
displayColumn: 8
```

[image]

Comment: add debugging code to your program

Comment: @jsotola I'v tried to get print of x, y from some code parts in some times and I have no idea anymore. After step 6 I found nothing activating the pixel. So seems the pixel still acive after previous teps but why so and why one? My experience is too poor to get it.

Comment: This can't be correct: `data = Text[i];  data <<= displayColumn;`. The first assignment will be overwritten by the second. It also looks odd that you are also incrementing  `displayColumn`  in the loop() as well as left shifting it in function shownum(). It will get some weird values in it. The original code, if it worked,  would have shown a '0'. What are you attempting to do, scroll the '0' from right to left across the display?

Comment: @6v6gt The second statement shifts the value in `data`. It is not a simple assignment overwriting the first. In contrast, the first statement is necessary to set a defined value in `data`.

Comment: @6v6gt yes, kinda. I don't know it looks odd or not cause I'm newbee in Arduino. But I see no logical contradictions in the order of assignment and besides it works strange but almost properly. The first assignment sets next byte ("the display line") in `data`, the second shifts it to left, and every 0.2 sec `displayColumn` increases by 1 ("one display column"). I try to animate original code slightly to understand better how to cook displays

Comment: Oops. I did not look at the the operator too closely. To me the code looks OK. You could try slowing the multiplexing down and look for any odd effects. When I work with a matrix display, I find it easier to define an array which matches the display, load the array, then write it out. This way, there is an intermediate state you can check.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, I checked the algorithm with debug prints, but no output to an LED matrix. -- Your wiring according to the drawing looks fine, too. -- Please [edit] your question to clarify: How long does this single erroneous LED light? Your code repeats endlessly. Does this happen?

Comment: @thebusybee done.

Comment: @6v6gt I'll try it but I found this way too verbose. I ran same code as you said for a 7-segments display experiment but the method with byte sequence looks more interesting and laconic for me, so I intend to figure out why I encountered the bug.

Comment: Does this phenomenon of the unwanted led remaining on show when the code is continually scrolling? Obviously, you stopped the cycle to make the pictures. With the way function Draw_point() is written, where the display is cleared and then a led is switched on, it is inevitable that if there is a pause anywhere, the last led switched on will remain on. As a crude test, you could add another clear() after the delay(1) in function Draw_point() or perhaps after show_num()  in the loop().

Comment: Please add debug prints like that: 1) For `x` and `y` in `Draw_point()` without line break. 2) `println()` after the `for` loop over `j` in `show_num()`. 3) For `displayColumn` after increment and rollover in `loop()` with line break. -- In my reproduction I added also a flag that avoids multiple outputs when `displayColumn` did not change, but the room here is limited. You might try to insert the same. -- Check that in the last round with `displayColumn` = 7 no output happens. It should be like that because your pattern has no bit 0 set.

Comment: Commonly you don't drive LEDs in reverse to switch them off. Instead you disable their driver, in case of the Arduino you will change the pin mode to input. However, I don't see how this could be an explanation to the effect you observe.

Comment: @thebusybee added and there's really no output after the seventh step. I also tried the flag as you said but this way cant draw symbol normally: LEDs just flash for a moment after every `displayColumn` chsnging. Looks like pin's state resets every loop iteration

Comment: @6v6gt the phenomenon is present when the scrilling stops at the final step too, no only when the scrolling is contineous. And yes, final `clear()` inside `Draw_point` turns the LED off, and now the code works as needed. Seems I understand your assertion about `clear()`, this function must be called before any row rendering. The original code draws static symbol so there `clear()` placed right. I just move it in `show_num` into first `for` as first line and now scrolling works correctly. You can write your comment as an answer little more detailed and I'll check it as correct

Comment: Good. I'm pleased it works now and it was an interesting puzzle. Maybe even another solution is simply to move the `clear()` from the beginning of `Draw_point()` to the end. That should also stop the unwanted led "lingering" for 200ms during the scroll. Anyway, I can't test it so I'll leave you to write up an answer and include the code in it that works best for you. Also note what @thebusybee  implied about making `clear()` more efficient. Feel free to mention my name in the answer.

Comment: I loaded your initial code into a simulator to try it. Unfortunately, the simulator does not have a raw 8x8 dot matrix and I can't spend too long creating one out of individual leds.
What I have done is modified Draw_point() to print out the time (ms) the last led was lit for (if > 5ms). It gives results like "xLast=7, yLast=6, on for 202 ms" and only that led which does not agree exactly with your statement "one LED (x=0, y=6) stays on.". Anyway, it is here: https://wokwi.com/projects/389152026616860673

Comment: @6v6gt seems in the original example circuit the display used in "landscape orientation" instead of "portrait" and its coordinate system is overturned. Thank you for helping very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found out during the discussion,
the display must be cleaned before drawing any new row. And since the `clear()` calling was at the beginning of the `Draw_point()` and this function was not used in the last step, cleaning was not executed before the last step. This is correct for static rendering but for scrolling it will be correct to move the `clear()` to the end of the `Draw_point()` then the project works correctly.

```
#define MY_PERIOD 200

int displayColumn = 0;
uint32_t tmr1;

unsigned char Text[] = { 0x00, 0x1c, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1c };

void Draw_point(unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
  digitalWrite(x + 2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, LOW);
  delay(1);
  clear();
}

void show_num(void) {
  unsigned char i, j, data;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    data = Text[i];
    data <<= displayColumn;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (data & 0x01) {
        Draw_point(j, i);
      }
      data >>= 1;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 2; i < 18; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  show_num();
  if (millis() - tmr1 >= MY_PERIOD) {
    tmr1 = millis();
    displayColumn++;
    if (displayColumn > 7) {
      displayColumn = 0;
    }
  }
}

void clear() {
  for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  for (int i = 10; i < 18; i++)
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
}
```

Thanks to users @6v6gt and @thebusybee for their help in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to your answer, this is for future visitors who want to learn more.

##### 1. Programming by Accident

Your analysis is correct, mine in an early comment is wrong.

The last LED of the second last "picture" is not cleared when the last "picture" is drawn. This is because you clear the matrix **only, if you switch on an LED.**

This is your original code:

```cpp
void Draw_point(unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
  clear();
  digitalWrite(x + 2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, LOW);
  delay(1);
}
```

In your solution you clear the complete matrix after the delay, which results in the expected effect.

However, you did not analyze the underlying to the end. You changed something after a random suggestion, and it "works." I have seen this so many times.

We know that `Draw_point()` handles only **one** LED. So we do not need to reset **all** pins to their respective off levels, 14 of the 16 are already fine. It suffices to do this for the single LED just switched on.

```cpp
void Draw_point(unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
  digitalWrite(x + 2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, LOW);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(x + 2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, HIGH);
}
```

##### 2. Driving the LEDs in Reverse

As I mentioned in a comment, you drive the LEDs of the matrix in reverse, when they are off. We all know that comments will not be read, mostly. So I add this here. ;-)

Most LEDs stand some voltage in reverse. According to the [788BS' data sheet](http://www.ledtoplite.com/uploadfile/2014/0807/20140807032939345.pdf) it has 5V as **absolute maximum** rating. I would not dare to apply that really.

All professionals drive their LED matrices such that only forward current is applied. All other LEDs are not driven at all.

The solution here is to change the pin mode of the pins.

```cpp
#define MY_PERIOD 200

int displayColumn = 0;
uint32_t tmr1;

unsigned char Text[] = { 0x00, 0x1c, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x1c };

void Draw_point(unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
  pinMode(x + 2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(x + 2, HIGH);
  pinMode(y + 10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(y + 10, LOW);
  delay(1);
  pinMode(x + 2, INPUT);
  pinMode(y + 10, INPUT);
}

void show_num(void) {
  unsigned char i, j, data;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    data = Text[i];
    data <<= displayColumn;
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (data & 0x01) {
        Draw_point(j, i);
      }
      data >>= 1;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  show_num();
  if (millis() - tmr1 >= MY_PERIOD) {
    tmr1 = millis();
    displayColumn++;
    if (displayColumn > 7) {
      displayColumn = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to `clear()` in `setup()`, because all pins are initially in "input" mode already.

##### 3. About Flicker

You tried with no `delay()` and see only a dim display. This is correct as the time the LED is on is short compared to the time of the rest of the program.

With `delay(2)` you experience flicker. Let's think about the timing here.

There are different "pictures" during the scroll, with the listed number of LEDs switch on:

| `displayColumn` | Number of LEDs switched on |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 16 |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 0 |

Because the Arduino is quite fast, we came approximate the calculations by neglecting the rest of the program.

Each single LED is shown for 2 ms according to `delay(2)`, so a complete picture sums up to repetition periods between (nearly) 0 ms (`displayColumn` = 7) and 32 ms (`displayColumn` = 0 to 2). The reciprocal gives us the display frequency, many know the term "frames per second" or frame rate. The lowest frame rate is with the longest period: 1 / 0.032 s = 31.25 Hz. Our eyes see this as flickering. BTW, as soon as the "picture" has fewer LEDs, the display will stop flickering.

Commonly human eyes see no flicker if the frame rate exceeds about 50 to 60 Hz. With `delay(1)` the periods are only half as long as with `delay(2)`, of course. The lowest frame rate is therefore 62.5 Hz, good enough for no flicker experience.

Please be aware that the frame rate drops with the number of LEDs switched on. If you want to have at least 50 Hz with `delay(1)`, you cannot have more than 20 LEDs: 1 / 50 Hz = 20 ms, which corresponds to 20 LEDs.

The solution here is to show a complete row at the same time. Because then there are just 8 rows to sequence, you can raise to `delay(2)` again: 8 rows * 2 ms < 20 ms. The specific code is left as an exercise to the reader. Please be aware that you need to take electrical maximum ratings into account. The MCU of the Arduino has limits to the sourced current.

##### 4. Final Note

You might wonder why the linked resource (the Keyestudio examples wiki) shows this "not-so-perfect" source code. Well, as we can see from the bad formatting of the example, it was hacked down in a hurry and without being aware that beginners will be misguided.

Take all such resources with a lot of caution. Unfortunately, this is absolutely necessary. *(This includes my answer here, too.)*

Comment: Just like that, I thought whatever my programm was far from optimum. I read your comment about mode switch but decided to search for materials on this topic because I never saw this method before, so thank you for the explaining with working example!
I also should to note that your first variant needs the `clear()` executed in the `setup()`.
And one final question - why exactly does `delay(1)` work as it should? No delay - symbol is dim because we switch it on and off instantly, it's too little time. But the display begins to flicker when delay = 2 or higher. Why 1?